# Solving the integral of a Modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: calculus, special-functions

I would like to find the answer for the following integral

$$\int x\ln(x)K_0(x) dx $$

where $K_0(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind and $\ln(x)$ is the natural-log. Do you have any ideas how to find?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you are a new user, here are some tips. for better results try showing some work or explaining the steps you tried and where you got stuck. Also make sure to remember to accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to answers provided by other users, once you find one which satisfies your question.

Comment: I edited your post. Is this the integral you meant?

Comment: yes. thank you for your effort.

Comment: @user53719: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Use integration by parts and the fact that $\int x K_0(x)dx = -x \frac{d}{dx}K_0(x)=-xK'_0(x)$

$$ \int x\ln(x)K_0(x)\,dx = -x\ln(x)K'_0(x) - \int (-x K'_0(x))(\frac{1}{x}) \, dx =\dots. $$

Answer (score 1):

Here's what *Mathematica* found:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks like an integration by parts to me (combined with an identity for modified Bessel functions).